# Error: $http is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I'm triying to make a controller/service for a state that get via my own query-method a list of clients.

It's weird because the "getAll" method works perfectly, the problem is query or some other get method... anyway, here is the service:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('omi.services')
    .factory('cliente', clienteFactory);

    clienteFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

    function clienteFactory ($http) {
      var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/omi/v1/clientes/';
      var service = {
        create  : create,
        getAll  : getAll,
        getOne  : getOne,
        query   : query,
        remove  : remove,
        update  : update
      };

      return service

      function create (clienteData) {
        // body...
      } // end create

      function getAll () {
        return $http.get(baseUrl)
          .success(getAllComplete)
          .error(getAllOnError);

        function getAllComplete (data) {
          return data;
        }
        function getAllOnError (data) {
          return data;
        }
      }
    } // end facturaFactory

    function getOne (cliente) {
      return $http.get(baseUrl + cliente)
        .success(getOneComplete)
        .error(getOneOnError);

      function getOneComplete (data) {
        return data;
      }
      function getOneOnError (data) {
        return data;
      }
    } // end getOne

    function query (query) {
      return $http.get(baseUrl + 'buscar' + query)
        .success(queryComplete)
        .error(queryOnError);

      function queryComplete (data) {
        return data;
      }
      function queryOnError (error) {
        return data;
      }
    } // end query

    function remove (factura) {
      // body
    } // end remove

    function update (clienteData) {
      // body...
    } // end update
})();
```

it's not complete yet, but is the entire structure. So, the problem is fired in the controller:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('omi.controllers')
    .controller('clientReportsResult', clientReports);

    clientReports.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'cliente'];

    function clientReports ($stateParams, cliente) {
      /* jshint validthis: true */
      var vm = this;
      vm.clientes = [];

      var id = $stateParams.data;
      var query = "?id=" + id;

      fire();

      function fire () {
        cliente.query(query).then(function(data) {
          vm.clientes = data.data.clientes;
        });
      }
    }
})();
```

It fire me this traceback:

```
"Error: $http is not defined
query@http://localhost:8080/js/services/clientes.service.js:55:7
fire@http://localhost:8080/js/controllers/clientes.reports.results.js:21:9
clientReports@http://localhost:8080/js/controllers/clientes.reports.results.js:18:7
invoke@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:4182:14
instantiate@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:4190:27
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:8449:18
$ViewDirectiveFill/<.compile/<@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3897:28
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:8213:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:7722:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:7075:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:6954:30
updateView@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3839:23
$ViewDirective/directive.compile/<@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3807:9
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:8213:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:7722:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:7075:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:7078:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:6954:30
$ViewDirectiveFill/<.compile/<@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3905:9
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:8213:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:7722:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:7075:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:6954:30
updateView@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3839:23
$ViewDirective/directive.compile/</<@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3801:11
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:14702:15
transitionTo/$state.transition<@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3218:11
processQueue@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:13170:27
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:13186:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:14383:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:14199:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:14488:13
done@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:9646:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:9836:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:8080/js/libs/angular/angular.js:9777:1
" "<div ui-view="" class="details ng-scope">"
```

I'm triying to solve the problem, but i can't understand the problem, why this error appear's here? In the others controllers where i use the "getAll" method all is working fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getOne` function is outside of your `clienteFactory` factory function where `$http` is defined, and `getAll` is in the scope.

This is the structure you have:

```
function clienteFactory ($http) {
  function getAll () {
  }
}

function getOne () {
   // $http is not defined here
}
```

Same is happening with `query`.

Put `getOne` and `query` inside the `clienteFactory`:

```
function clienteFactory ($http) {
  function getAll () {
  }

  function getOne () {
  }

  function query() {
  }
}
```